# Time continuity in $H^1_0$ for weak solution to $u_t - \Delta u = u \log |u|$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, parabolic-pde

I don't know how to prove this example.
let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded with smooth boundary. Assume that $u=u(x, t)$ on $\Omega \times [0, T)$ satisfies:
\begin{equation}
u\in L^{\infty}(0, T; H_0^1(\Omega)), u_t\in L^2(0, T; L^2(\Omega))
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(u_t, v)_{L^2}+(\nabla u, \nabla v)_{L^2} = (u\log|u|, v)_{L^2}, \mbox{for any}\ v\in H_0^1(\Omega), t\in(0, T).
\end{equation}
then $\|u(t_1)-u(t_2)\|_{H_0^1}\to 0$ as $t_1\to t_2$.

Comment: I think the idea is to put $v = u(t_1) - u(t_2)$ into the weak PDE, and then do a few inequalities.  How have some kind of Poincare/Sobolev type inequality that tells you $\|u \log|u|\|_2 \le C \|u\|_{H^1_0}$ which should help.

Comment: Can you add more context, e.g. where do you find this question?

Answer (score 1):

By the Sobolev inequality,
$$ \|u\|_p \le C_1 \|u\|_{H_0^1} ,$$
for any $p>2$ satisfying $\frac1p \ge \frac12 - \frac1n$.  Also
$$ \| u \log |u| \|_2 \le C_2 \| u\|_p .$$

Let $\phi_n$ be the eigenvalues of the Laplacian on $\Omega$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions.  Then every function in $L^2$ can be written as
$$ u = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (u, \phi_k) \phi_k .$$
Let
$$ S_n u  = u_n = \sum_{k=1}^n (u, \phi_k) \phi_k .$$
Thus $\Delta S_n = S_n \Delta$, and $S_n^2 = S_n$.

Now put $-\Delta u_n$ into the weak PDE to get
$$ \frac12 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} {\|\nabla  u_n\|}_2^2 + 
{\|\Delta u_n\|}_2^2 \le {\|\Delta u_n \|}_2 {\| u \|}_{H^1_0} 
\le \frac12 {\|\Delta u_n \|}_2^2 +  2{\| u \|}_{H^1_0}^2 ,$$
that is
$$ \frac12 {\|\nabla  u_n(t)\|}_2^2 - \frac12 {\|\nabla  u_n(0)\|}_2^2 + 
\frac12 \int_0^t {\|\Delta u_n(s) \|}_2^2 \, ds \le  2 \int_0^t {\| u(s) \|}_{H^1_0}^2 \, ds .$$
Let $n \to \infty$.  Then
$$ {\|u\|}_{L^\infty H^1_0}^2 + 
{\| u\|}_{L^2 H^2_0} ^2 \le {\| u(0)\|}_{H^1_0}^2 + 4 {\| u \|}_{L^2 H^1_0}^2 .$$
So $u \in L^2 H^2_0$.

Now put $v = \Delta u_n(t_1) - \Delta u_n(t_0)$ into the weak PDE, and integrate with respect to $t$ from $t_0$ to $t_1$.
\begin{align} \|u_n(t_1) - u_n(t_0)\|_{H^1_0}^2 &= \int_{t_0}^{t_1} ( v,\partial_t u(t))_{L^2} \, dt
\\&= - \int_{t_0}^{t_1} ( \nabla v, \nabla u(t) )_{L^2} dt + \int_{t_0}^{t_1} ( v, u(t)\log|u(t)| )_{L^2} dt
\\&\le \| v \|_{H_0^2} \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \|u(t)\|_{H_0^2} \, dt + C_1 C_2 \|v\|_{H_0^2} \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \|u(t)\|_{H_0^1} \, dt .
\end{align}
(I got a bit lazy at the end, so you might want to double check it.)  And
$$ \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \|u(t)\|_{H_0^1} \, dt \to 0 $$
as $t_1 \to t_2$.

Comment: Dear Stephen Montgomery-Smith. Thank you very much. 
I'm sorry, I'm not good at English. 
I have some concerns, is < , > L^2 norm?

Comment: Yes.  I guess I should have used parentheses like you did in the question.

Comment: I changes it to the notation you used.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so courteously.　I'll keep getting better.

Comment: Dear Stephen Montgomery-Smith.　I'm sorry to bother you over and over. 　This proof showed the continuity of L^2. How does the continuity of H_0^1 show from here?

Comment: You are correct.  I got it wrong!

Comment: Thank you very very much! I'm still a bachelor. There are many concepts that I do not understand. 
I will try to read the proof after studying the unknown part. Thank you for a long time:)

Comment: Dear Stephen Montgomery-Smith

>First, use v=Δ^2u_ϵ in the weak PDE. From this you will get u∈L^2(H^2_0).

I'm sorry...I want you to tell me this part in detail.　Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I rewrote the answer with more details.  I had meant \nabla^2 u_n